# Switch device. Tabbing onto button default behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I'm having a hard time finding any resources that talk about best practice, default behaviours and so forth.

Basically, I have a button on a page. It doesn't do anything, I essentially have a `canvas` element and just needed a way for the user to be able to tab onto the page.

So using a switch device, I can navigate to the button, and on clicking on the button, it jumps me back up to the url address bar. The behaviour I'm after is on selecting the button it still stays on the same page.

I've tested other websites and it looks like the default behaviour is that once  you select a button it jumps to the top of the page.

Could anyone point me in the direction of any resources or anything that confirms or talks about this?

I essentially only have this:

`<button tabindex="1" class="action_button">Action trigger button</button>`

and a

`<canvas></canvas>` element

Comment: Remove the `tabindex="1"` as that forces it to trump all other tab-stops on the page. `<button>` is natively keyboard accessible so you do not need it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this relates to [the default `type` of buttons being `submit`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type)

Does adding `type="button"` to the button change the behaviour you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will happen unless you add some script to the button. If you have no other action for the button you can use this:

function() {return false;}

But if the button doesn't do anything you should remove it - people who rely on keyboard navigation don't usually like having to work their way though unnecessary controls. If there is nothing interactive then don't make them tab into the page. (Also there is no need to add tabindex to a button, it takes focus natively.)